# Prompt to restart a process for administrative privilege

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am the only user and admin of my computer. My account doesn't have password because the computer is located in a secret room. I want to restart a process as administrator.

I don't want to change manifest because it makes the process to run always on administrative privilege.

I want administrative privilege only when I need it.

Using functions `CreateProcessWithLogon`, `LogonUser` and command tool `runas.exe` is not appropriate for me because I have no password.

What can I do? Moreover when I run an application as administrator, it prompts but it doesn't ask for password. Is there any way to make such a prompt?

Comment: Actually I want to do this via c code

Comment: `ShellExecute` then. Specify "runas".

Comment: If you have UAC enabled, then you are going to have to interact with the new process in some way. Typically with the UAC consent dialog. If you actually want to run processes without such interaction, disable UAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Moreover when I run an application as administrator,it prompts but it doesn't ask for password.Is there any way to make such a prompt?

It would ask you for the password if you attempted to run the application as administrator from user account with limited user rights (non-admin).

If you wish to run under admin rights only when you really need them, you should split your application to two parts: one part would run under limited rights, the other, only capable to do the administrative actions and nothing more, would be run only at need (so it should not "run away").

Comment: 2 manifest in 1 application is not possible. Did you suggesting me to make 2 applications?

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion.

Comment: You certainly don't need two apps, the `runas` verb allows you to do this with a single executable file. User will still need to interact with the UAC dialog which I think is what asker would like to avoid.